# How to defer creating/displaying boxes in front end until requested?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, undocumented, display, boxes

If the size of an output expression is larger than threshold `ByteCount`, the front end will display an abbreviated version of it by producing an `OutputSizeLimit` object to avoid spending too much time on making boxes out of the full expression:

```
Array[x, 10000]
```

[image]

The boxes are made only when the "show all" button is pressed.

How can this behavior of defering the making of boxes be extended to other forms of output, like in a [`SummaryBox`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79891/2048)?

Consider the `SummaryBox` form of `MyObject` defined as

```
ClearAll[MyObject];
MyObject /:  MakeBoxes[obj : MyObject[asc_], form_] := 
  Module[{above, below}, 
    above = {{BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Name: ", asc["Name"]}], SpanFromLeft}, 
             {BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Variables: ", asc["Variables"]}],  
              BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Length: ", asc["Length"]}]}};
    below = {BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Date: ", asc["Date"]}],
             BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Metadata: ", asc[MetaInformation]}]};

    BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[MyObject,obj, Null,above,below,form]
  ];
```

Then the following expression will take a long time (like 5 full seconds) to appear on screen

```
Table[MyObject[<|"Name" -> "My particular object",
     "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, "Date" -> Today, 
     MetaInformation -> Array[x, 10000]|>], 20]
```

[image]

because, even though it is not displayed explicitly, it's presumably spending a lot of time making the boxes for each `Array` (as part of `MetaInformation`).

Is there a way to *defer* the making of boxes only to when the `+` button is pressed, like when the "show all" button is pressed in an `OutputSizeLimit` object?

The answer does not need to be given specifically in terms of `SummaryBox`.  A simple dynamic front end object illustrating how it can be done in principle would suffice.  I'm looking for key `FrontEnd` functions that can be used to defer the making of boxes.

Comment: You could try ``BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Metadata: ", Dynamic @ asc[MetaInformation]}]``, which cuts the time in half for me. Still pretty slow, though.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not actually the making of the boxes that's the killer. It's the display of them. For some reason the FE itself is doing this incredibly slowly (and there's not much I can think of to speed this up). As confirmation use Carl Woll's ``Dynamic @`` trick and then run it through `AbsoluteTiming @ ToBoxes`. It takes a fraction of a second. Displaying it still takes like 3.

Comment: But if it's hidden behind the `+` it doesn't need to display it.  What exactly is the part you say is taking a long time?

Comment: @QuantumDot I don't know what it's doing, maybe making all those `DynamicModuleBoxes`. But the `ToBoxes` takes 0.60s and putting the things on screen takes 2.09, even with the `Dynamic` and hidden stuff. It might simply need to pass too much data. I think that might actually be it, as dropping the `Array` size to `100` to box creation and rendering times become much more similar.

Answer (score 5):

You can speed things up considerably by using a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic) as I suggested in the OP comments, and using [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed) instead of [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule). Here is the `MyObject` definition using [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic):

```
ClearAll[MyObject];
MyObject /:  MakeBoxes[obj : MyObject[asc_], form_] := Module[{above, below}, 
    above = {
        {
        BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Name: ", asc["Name"]}],
        SpanFromLeft
        }, 
        {
        BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Variables: ", asc["Variables"]}],
        BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Length: ", asc["Length"]}]
        }
    };
    below = {
        BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Date: ", asc["Date"]}],
        BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Metadata: ", Dynamic @ asc[MetaInformation]}]
    };

    BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[MyObject,obj, Null,above,below,form]
]
```

And here is a list of `MyObject` objects using [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed) instead of [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule):

```
list = Table[
    MyObject[
        <|
        "Name" -> "My particular object",
        "Length" -> 10,
        "Variables" -> {a, b, c},
        "Date" -> Today, 
        MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]
        |>
    ],
    20
];
```

Now, box generation is fast:

```
boxes = ToBoxes @ list; //AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.425972, Null}

And, rendering is fast:

```
start = AbsoluteTime[];
list
```

> {MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]], MyObject[
>   Association[
>     "Name" -> "My particular object", "Length" -> 10, "Variables" -> {a, b, c}, 
>      "Date" -> DateObject[{2018, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>      MetaInformation :> Array[x, 10000]]]}

```
AbsoluteTime[] - start
```

> 0.265248

Another idea is to not include the `Metadata` field in the summary box, but instead make it accessible with a property extractor, e.g.:

```
MyObject[asc_Association]["Metadata"] := asc[MetaInformation]
```

Comment: I think the `RuleDelayed` is doing the heavy lifting here (although of course the `Dynamic` is necessary). It looks like passing the data to and from the front-end is the rate limiting step here. So cutting down on the bytes passed is the key.

Comment: @b3m2a1 yes otoh `Array[x, 10000]` is an artificial example and in general it is the real data. So at the end the rule is, don't put there heavy stuff. I tried to use this trick here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160938/5478 but `Temporary` symbols generated during typesetting are cleared differently than those from regular evaluation O_o

Comment: @Kuba. Yes, this solution doesn't work for me because in my use case, the data `Array[x, 10000]` is *already* to be in evaluated form.